# Typescript import module problems

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, rxjs

This is my project structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiaBM.png)

Modules were introduced into the src->app->modules->auth->reducers->authorizeHandler file

I can see that it introduces index.ts under src->app->modules, but I don't know where it links to this directory without using a relative path.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qulrn.png)

I used the global search keyword similar to declare module 'modules', modules are not found.

Comment: Edit your question to include provided images as question context using the img tag of the SO editor.

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me.